# Passing `training=true` when using doing tensorflow training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

TensorFlow's official tutorial says that we should pass base_model(trainin=False) during training in order for the BN layer not to update mean and variance. my question is: why? why we don't need to update mean and variance, I mean BN has imagenet mean and variance and why it is useful to use imagenet's mean and variance, and not update them on new data? even during fine tunning, in this case whole model updates weights but BN layer still is going to have imagenet mean and variance.
edit: i am using this tutorial :https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning

Comment: Please share a link to official tutorial you are using

Comment: @AlexK. https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When model is trained from initialization, batchnorm should be enabled to tune their mean and variance as you mentioned. Finetuning or transfer learning is a bit different thing: you already has a model that can do more than you need and you want to perform particular specialization of pre-trained model to do your task/work on your data set. In this case part of weights are frozen and only some layers closest to output are changed. Since BN layers are used all around model you should froze them as well. Check again this explanation:

> Important note about BatchNormalization layers Many models contain
> tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization layers. This layer is a special
> case and precautions should be taken in the context of fine-tuning, as
> shown later in this tutorial.
>
> When you set layer.trainable = False, the BatchNormalization layer
> will run in inference mode, and will not update its mean and variance
> statistics.
>
> When you unfreeze a model that contains BatchNormalization layers in
> order to do fine-tuning, you should keep the BatchNormalization layers
> in inference mode by passing training = False when calling the base
> model. Otherwise, the updates applied to the non-trainable weights
> will destroy what the model has learned.

Source: [transfer learning](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning), details regarding [freeze](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/transfer_learning#freezing_layers_understanding_the_trainable_attribute)

Comment: I understand but what about when they unfreeze all the weights? it seems that all the weights are updated except BN mean and variance, is it still correct?

Comment: In my opinion if you unfreeze all weights, initial pre-train does not matter at that point. You will get almost same result as from random init. So this scenario is possible but not useful.

Comment: I mean, you train network's head then you unfreeze whole model. in this case they still use BN layers in inference mode

Comment: Check this [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63020188/14161847). Main idea unfreezing BN makes a little to no sense usage of pretrained model.